# Entity Framework PowerShell script cannot be loaded by Visual Studio because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, visual-studio-2017, executionpolicy, package-manager-console

When I load Package Manager Console within Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.6 in a project that uses Entity Framework I receive the following error:

> \packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\init.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction 
>   policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.
>   At line:1 char:45
>   + ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Bitbucket\project-path\packages\EntityFramework.6.2. ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

This prevents me from running commands specific to Entity Framework like "Update-Database" or "Add-Migration".

Here are things I have tried:

1. Reinstall Visual Studio
2. In Group Policy Editor, for both Computer Configuration and User Configuration, I have enabled the setting "Turn on Script Execution" that is located at "Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell". The setting for both configurations has the "Execution Policy" set to "Allow all scripts". [image: screenshot of script execution setting]
3. I've tried locally in the Package Manager Console setting the "Process" scope to both "Bypass" and "Unrestricted", and then manually loading the Entity Framework init.ps1 script. I receive the same error.
4. I've also tried modifying registry keys for PowerShell to set the ExecutionPolicy to "Unrestricted" in a few places. Those places are at:

   - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell
   - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps120
   - HKLM\Software\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.sqlps140
5. I've restarted multiple times in between doing all of the above.

When I run the command "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List", here are my results"

```
Scope         ExecutionPolicy
----- -----------------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
UserPolicy       Unrestricted
Process             Undefined
CurrentUser      Unrestricted
LocalMachine     Unrestricted
```

After all of the above I expected to be able to just load Visual Studio as normal, launch Package Manager Console, and not receive any errors when it tries to run the Entity Framework init.ps1 script. I must be missing something or doing something incorrectly. What do I need to do to get Visual Studio to work as expected?

Some more information is that this is a computer joined to a company domain, but no other developers have this issue. There isn't a group policy set by an administrator that is trickling down preventing me from running scripts.

Comment: Try changing your policies to `Bypass` instead of `Unrestricted`.

Comment: I have set the policies for `CurrentUser` and `LocalMachine` to `Bypass`. `UserPolicy` is still set to `Unrestricted` as it can only be set through the group policy editor, and there's no option in there for `Bypass`. I am still having the same issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error may be occurring because of an invalid certificate from Microsoft. Check in Control Panel => Internet Options => Content => Certificates on the Untrusted Publishers tab. Remove Microsoft Corporation from this list.

Sounds bizarre but it worked for me.

Tks https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7158

Comment: Wow. This was it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Remove file inside

control=>internet option => content => certificates =>Untrusted publishers

then problem will solve

Answer (score 0):

### Try downgrading to EF 6.1.2.

I ran into the same problem as you. I tried changing the Group Execution Policies which in my case didn't work, because of some restriction on my local machine (may be set by my school admin). In another project I used 6.1.2 where things like migration was no problem.

Comment: You can also downgrade to 6.1.3, just downgrade to minor version 1